# problem with the symbology and definition of a symbol

Tags: notation, positive-matrices

I'm reading a paper that appears: given n x n matrix A, the kth exterior power $Λ^{k}A$, and I don't know what this $Λ^{k}$,  symbol means  , I think that it is the minor k x k  of the matrix A, but I do not know if I am correct or not.

Comment: Where did you see this? They probably defined the symbol earlier in the paper. Please share the source where you saw this notation.

Comment: file:///C:/Users/sergi/Downloads/Introductory%20Notes%20on%20Total%20Positivity%20(1).pdf

this is the paper but there they never mentioned what this symbol means

Comment: That is the location of the file on your local machine; we can't follow that link.

Comment: It's possible that this is meant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_matrix#Relation_to_exterior_powers

Comment: this is the link @BrianTung https://people.brandeis.edu/~aminul/Docs/ira/ISING/intp+ve.pdf